# Running aptana studio on Ubuntu with php

Tags: aptana

I have just installed Ubuntu.

I am a new user to ubuntu but have managed to get php/mysql working as verified by localhost.

I downloaded aptana studio,created a php project and did a simple .php page.When I go to run the page by pressing the green arrow.

I get a popup with the following error.

```
"Unable to launch"

The selection cannot be launced,and there are no recent launches
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aptana Studio does not include a PHP server for previewing, so you need to set one up. Since you already have a server, you just need to connect Studio to preview against that. There is a document here that explains the process:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Setting+up+an+external+web+server+to+preview+PHP+and+other+non-HTML+pages

Comment: Thanks.Article was very helpful